# The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm trying to build my Apache Cordova app for Google Play and I'm facing with this error although I included `xlmns:tools`.
I've tried all solutions in the Internet but still get this error!
Where is the problem?

My code:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    id="com.mypackage" versionCode="1.8.4" version="1.8.4">  

 <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
...     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" 
      tools:node="remove"/>
...
</config-file>
</widgets>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue using the [cordova-custom-config plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) for Ionic and solved adding the following xml tag enclosed within the platform tag:

```
<custom-preference name="android-manifest/@xmlns:tools" value="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
```

Basically, the above code adds a xmlns to the manifest node for the AndroidManifest.xml file and the error will disappear.